# call to a member function on a non object codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

So this is really infuriating but i am getting:

Fatal error: Call to a member function insert_review() 
on a non-object in /application/controllers/user_submissions.php on line 58

1. I've preloaded the database library in my config so it's nothing to do with that.
2. My controllers and models are spelled correctly.

### ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'www.mydomain.com/user_submissions/save_entry',
    data: { 'user_email' : user_email, 'data' : dataobj}
}).done(function(data) {}).fail(function() {}).always(function() {});
}
 });
```

I'm receiving the data in my controller, in an array: however I cannot send it to my model, why?

### user submission controller:

```
class User_submissions extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
         parent::__construct();
         $this->load->model('add_entry');
    }

    public function save_entry()
    {
         $user_data = $this->input->post();
         $user_data['date_created']  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");    
         $this->add_entry->insert_review($user_data);
    }
}
```

### my model:

```
class add_entry extends CI_Model
{

    private $user_reviews = 'User_review';

    public function insert_review($data)
    {
       //i never reach this point:
       $this->db->insert($this->user_reviews, $data); 
       echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to load your model in function itself

Comment: whats your model file name? does it matches with the class name?

Comment: @kailashYadav first thing I tried, same error.

Comment: @nil'z yes it matches

Answer (score 0):

I guess your model name is not proper , Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

Check this link for more information [Models codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

Comment: They are the same name. I'm reaching the model successfully just not the insert_review function

Comment: Hmmm, your model don't have constructor  `function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }`

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was to comment out:  `$this->load->model('add_entry');` in my constructor and call it in my function instead:

```
public function save_entry()
    {
         $this->load->model('add_entry');
         $user_data = $this->input->post();
         $user_data['date_created']  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");    
         $this->add_entry->insert_review($user_data);
    }
```

Could someone explain to me why this works?

Answer (score 0):

try this..you have load your model with construct method like this

```
class add_entry extends CI_Model
{

    private $user_reviews = 'User_review';

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct(); //load construct method
    }

    public function insert_review($data)
    {
       //i never reach this point:
       $this->db->insert($this->user_reviews, $data); 
       echo $this->db->last_query();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think your model is not loading properly and check your model class path.

```
$this->load->model('blog/queries');
```